# Saving to specific folder with Drive Picker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'd like to save uploaded files to a specific folder, not root. Google's Picker Class Reference specifies using DocsUploadView.setParent("folderID"), however I can't figure out how to access this property in App Maker.
Thanks!

Comment: For now I'm moving the file via a server script after uploading, it's working fine:      function moveFileToFolder(fileId, targetFolderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
    newFolder.addFile(file);
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
    
}

Comment: You should put this as an answer and accept it.